# SSRS parameter to display results on single page

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that displays active jobs per employee. At the moment the report returns each job per employee (and correlating information with that particular job) on a single page and then the next job on the next page. Job numbers can vary depending on which employee is selected.

The user wants the option to either display the report across multiple pages or on a single page, depending on how they wish to utilize the report.

I know you can change the properties to display all results on one page by adjusting the height property to 0. However, this will not give the user an option to display the report on multiple pages.

Is there a way to add an option when the report is being run to display the results on a single page?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the **Page Break** property doesn't allow expressions to allow it to be dynamic. You would have to choose whether to have page breaks or not and can only change it by going into the report designer to change it.

What you could try, is create a new table (or copy the old one) with the same grouping but remove the page break so that it doesn't break up by job.

Then add a parameter to choose which one to show with **Available Values** as single or multi (or whatever you want to call them).

You can then set the **Hidden** property on the tables. Set the original table to hide when **single** is selected:

```
=IIF(Parameters!PAGE.Value = "single", True, False)
```

And set the new table to the opposite:

```
=IIF(Parameters!PAGE.Value = "single", True, False)
```

This will allow you to show the version of the table based on the parameter selected.

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks Heaps